# Value to rgb value

Tags: python

I want to convert a value between 0 and 1 to a rgb value, based on the following:

[image]

How would you do this in python?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Isn't it clear that the graph provides a mapping from `[0,1]` to RGB already? You just need to construct a piecewise function for each function (`R(x)`, `G(x)`, and `B(x)`).

Answer (score 2):

Try the [colorsys](http://docs.python.org/library/colorsys.html#module-colorsys) module.  Converting HSB with Hue as your variable and Saturation and Brightness both at 1.0 should give something like that.

Comment: The component mapping for HSV is somewhat different from the one in the picture above. Shifted by about 150 degrees, from the look of it; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Converting_to_RGB

Comment: @RolandSmith good point - it doesn't actually match up properly - it's not cyclical either.  I guess it has to be a matter of rolling your own function then.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for a python lookup table solution returned this really useful example:
http://www.zovirl.com/2008/11/04/interpolated-lookup-tables-in-python/

An example of your red channel LUT might be:

```
points = ((.4,.2), (.6,1.), (.9,1.), (1.,.5))
table = InterpolatedArray(points)
print table[.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the three color functions have the save shape, and from the look of it are even identical. So you could get away with defining a single function, and then calling it with offsetted input to generate R,G and B values. Hint; look at the graph for the green component. This is basically a rising line in the domain 0-0.5 and descending line in the domain 0.5-1. Extrapolate to find the points where the green lines intersect with color = 0.0 (this is the bottom of the rising line, will be < 0), color = 1.0 and each other (this is the top of the rigins line, will be < 1), and use that to program the function for the green component. Then limit the return values between 0 and 1.

```
def component(x):
  '''Function for the green component.'''
  top = 1.5
  bottom = -0.5
  if x < 0.5:
    rv = x/0.5*(top-bottom)+bottom
  else:
    rv = (x-0.5)/0.5*(bottom-top)+top
  if rv > 1.0:
    return 1.0
  if rv < 0.0:
    return 0.0
  return rv
```

(the values for `top` and `bottom` are estimates; measure the graph!)

Now for the other colors; Note how the red graph leaves the 0-line at a bigger color valua than the green one. So to use the green component function to get the red color, subtract the horizontal distance between the red and green graphs from the input value before feeding it to the function to calculate the green value. For the blue value, you have to add someting instead of subtracting it.